# Submission of Augmented Reality iOS Applications to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, augmented-reality

I’m developing an AR application for iOS, for a range of toys. The concept of it is essentially that on the physical toy is a marker that the camera will detect, and overlay a 3D scene.

My question is regarding submission of AR applications to the App Store. What are the requirements around providing AR Markers for App Store approvers to test with?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: I would suggest contacting Apple directly regarding your requirements. I believe that they will need a demo marker to properly test the app functionality so you would have to coordinate that with them.

Comment: @DanielD check my answer. I have mentioned the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the image marker into any web server, then you can provide a link for Apple in Review notes. Apple requires demo marker to access its features.

Answer (score 2):

I have developed an AR application which incorporates image detection feature. What I have done is that I have placed few sample images on an image hosting server and provided the link for the same as review notes to the reviewer while filling up the MetaData.

If you need to know which app I have developed, heres the link : [Alive TOI](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alive-toi/id561048342?ls=1&mt=8).

Those images are active ever since I first uploaded the application.

Unfortunately, I cannot reveal those images but this is the tried and testified method. The proof is that I have an approved app on app store.

Hope this helps.