# Using ARKIT Image recognise app publish issue on app store

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, appstore-approval, image-recognition

I have uploaded My App to Appstore but they rejected with this reason (AR Camera View Image Detection).

**Application Functionality**
- detect image and play video
- image are store in AR Resource asset

**From Apple**
- we were still unable to locate a method of obtaining the AR markers in your app.

so can you help me for that and what is the AR Marker?.

Comment: I think they are asking that image you are gonna scan to play video  are static or you are getting that from your server.

Comment: this image got from books and exhibition hall.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006429/submission-of-augmented-reality-ios-applications-to-app-store

Comment: Can you please post your marker images inside AR Resource?

Comment: i am using 2d simple images,there is one page in my application , this three image there and instruction also there after that one button click i am open ar camera scene view.what will help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is very strict with regard to apps that use marker recognition, because Apple wants to make sure the end user has an optimal experience. If AR experience requires a marker image, it is important to inform the user how to and from where to obtain the marker image.

There are two main things to to do:

- It's important to include the marker image when submitting your app
  to the store.
- Within your app's UI you have to inform the user what
  marker image to use and how to obtain the marker.

**Please note:** *From my experience Apple will also reject apps that force the user to purchase a physical product in order to unlock content. Any paywall/purchase requirement would have to be through an in-app purchase*

Comment: marker is one type image right ? whatever image we are going to detect this image allready in app

Comment: Yes a 2D image is one type of marker that you can have. ARkit also has 3D markers which are real world objects that you scan and create a marker file for (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects)

Comment: Regardless of what type of marker you use, whenever you build a marker based Apple requires you to inform the user how to activate the experience (via your app's UI in some way).

Comment: i am using 2d simple images,there is one page in my application , this three image there and instruction also there after that one button click i am open ar camera scene view.

Comment: that should work. make sure to provide the images whenever you submit your app

Comment: i allready doing that but they are asking ar marker every time. in my case these image is a marker , there is any difference simple image and marker ? or is there any way to generate ar marker with image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193293/discussion-between-bhavik-panchal-and-hermes).

Answer (score 0):

There is two type marker and markless . markless mean some animation image will show the camera . marker means if you target something means you will show the marker image inside the target image .

Comment: if image detected then i need to show some image like right tik or any thing

Comment: can you give me example of this type image it will help for me

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ar+marker+image&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip_93IxJjiAhXPAnIKHW5CCKcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1572&bih=831#imgrc=ZmcDX2yJmFaQ5M:       this one is the example ..That rectangular mark can detact and show the AR image

Comment: in your project can you  use this type of image?

Comment: i have ar image if this image can be match than i am playing video

Comment: whatever image i am detecting this image in ar asset in project